# String intern for GC

Tags: java, string, garbage-collection

I have read many artiles regarding string interning.

If I create a String object

**Method 1**

```
  String str= new String("test")
```

2 Objects are created one in heap and other in string pool.

**Method 2 if method 1 is not executed**

```
  String str= new String("test").intern()
```

it will create a copy of string frpoom heap to string pool .How many objects will be created.I guess 3.One will be in heap ,other in pool and one "test" literal.

Which one will be eligible for GC in both cases.I have seen artilces that say 2 are getting created but i am unable to understand why?

**Method 3**

```
    String s= new String("test")
    String s1=s.intern()
```

It does the same thing except the s point to heap object and s1 to pool object and none of them are eligible for Gc.

Is my understanding correct???I am confused a lot on this concept.

Comment: String interning is not a feature a typical Java program needs to make use of. I am astounded how many questions about the feature are asked, while after years of writing and reading Java code for a living, I have not ever seen intern() used in production code. It may therefore not be cause for concern if you do not understand how String interning works exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I create a String object
>
> ```
>  String str= new String("test")
> ```
>
> Objects are created one in heap and other in string pool.

A String consists of two objects, the `String` and the `char[]` In some version of Java it could be a `byte[]` Or in fact a `char[]` which is later replaced by a `byte[]`. This means that 4, perhaps 5 objects could be created, unless the String for the string literal already exists, in which cases it is 2 for Java 7 update 4+, before that the `char[]` would be shared so it could be three objects or only 1.

> ```
> String str= new String("test").intern()
> ```

This is exactly the same except, if this is called enough the `new String` could be allocated on the stack and you might find that only the char[]` is created and this cannot be placed on the stack, at the moment. In future this might be optimised away also.

> Which one will be eligible for GC in both cases.I have seen artilces that say 2 are getting created but i am unable to understand why?

The answer is anywhere from 1 to 4 depending on the situation. All of there eligible for collection unless they are being strongly referenced somewhere.

Comment: The string literal always 'already exists'. The compiler created it.

Answer (score 0):

Points to note is

1. Interning is automatic for `String` literals, the `intern()` method is to be used on Strings constructed with new `String()`
2. The `Strings` (more specifically, string objects) will be garbage collected if they ever become unreachable, like any other java objects.
3. String `literals` typically are not candidates for garbage collection. There will be a implicit reference from the Object to that literal.
4. Reason for `point#3` is If a literal is being used inside a method to build a  `String` is reachable for as long as the method could be executed.

Answer (score 0):

**String intern() method:**

The most common methods for String comparison are the `equals()` and `equalsIgnoreCase()` methods. However, these methods may need large amount of memory for large sequence of characters. The Java String  `intern()` method helps us to improve the performance of the comparison between two Strings.

The  `intern()` method, when applied to a String object, returns a reference to this object (from the hash set of Strings that Java makes), that has the same contents as the original object. Thus, if a code uses the `intern()` method for several String objects, then our program will use significantly less memory , because it will reuse the references of the objects in the comparison between these Strings.

Keep in mind, that Java automatically interns String literals. This means that the  `intern()` method is to be used on Strings that are constructed with new `String()`.

Example:

```
JavaStringIntern.java

package com.javacodegeeks.javabasics.string; 
public class JavaStringIntern { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        String str1 = "JavaCodeGeeks"; 
        String str2 = "JavaCodeGeeks"; 
        String str3 = "JavaCodeGeeks".intern(); 
        String str4 = new String("JavaCodeGeeks"); 
        String str5 = new String("JavaCodeGeeks").intern(); 
        System.out.println("Are str1 and str2 the same: " + (str1 == str2)); 
        System.out.println("Are str1 and str3 the same: " + (str1 == str3)); 
        System.out.println("Are str1 and str4 the same: " + (str1 == str4)); //this should be "false" because str4 is not interned         
        System.out.println("Are str1 and str4.intern() the same: " + (str1 == str4.intern())); //this should be "true" now                 
        System.out.println("Are str1 and str5 the same: " + (str1 == str5)); 
    } 
} 

Output:
Are str1 and str2 the same: true
Are str1 and str3 the same: true
Are str1 and str4 the same: false
Are str1 and str4.intern() the same: true
Are str1 and str5 the same: true
```

Comment: Why would these methods 'need large amount of memory for large sequined of characters'?